# Send Parse JSON Push from web interface

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm trying to send JSON Push to my iPhone from the Parse web interface and it doesn't work.

The web service tell me the status is Done and the notification is "No Alert" but I dont have any notification on my iPhone ...

This is what I get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCh2F.png

And this is the JSON that I send :

```
{ "data": { "alert": "A test notification from Parse!" } }
```

And yes a simple push with message (no JSON) works fine.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try `{ "aps": { "alert": "A test notification from Parse!" } }`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following JSON with a single level and it worked for me (showing correctly title and alert message):

```
{
    "title": "<the title goes here>",
    "alert": "<the message goes here>",
}
```

Also what i found out from code is, if you don't do any magic by overriding ParsePushBroadcastReceiver's onPushOpen, you can add an *uri* and an *action*. For example this one we use to send users to Play with an information about an available update (if there version is very outdated):

```
{
    "title": "<the title goes here>",
    "alert": "<the message goes here>",
    "uri": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package name>",
    "action": "android.intent.action.VIEW"
}
```